# Create a dictionary and store values in Obj C

Tags: objective-c

I'm really new to Obj-C and iOS development, and have set up a storyboard and the basic controllers.

I'm now trying to do some basic storage of user-inputs in a dictionary, but am not 100% sure on how to set up dictionaries. I've gone through the docs but am a bit stuck.

Basically, I'd like to achieve:

1. Create a dictionary
2. Access the input value from "`titleTextField`" and set that as the value for the key `title`
3. Then I'd just like to access that value using the key from the dictionary, and NSLog it just to confirm.

I've pasted in the code, see the function at the bottom, but am not 100% sure if I have the syntax on all the properties right. You can see the @property 's defined at the top of the page, and then I try access those in the `addButtonTapped` function at the bottom.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated!

```
//  AddViewController.m
//  TodoApp
//

#import "AddViewController.h"

@interface AddViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *notesTextView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *titleTextField;
- (IBAction)addButtonTapped:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;

@end

@implementation AddViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)addButtonTapped:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Add button tapped");

    //Create dictionary and store the values from the text fields and views

    NSMutableDictionary *items = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:_titleTextField,@"title", nil];
    [items setObject:_titleTextField forKey:@"title"];




}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. This is the sort of thing you're looking for:

```
- (IBAction)addButtonTapped:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Add button tapped");

    // Create dictionary and store the values from the text fields and views
    // This is a class method, which you can tell because it is called
    // with NSMutableDictionary as its receiver.
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    // This is the modern way to set dictionary values. You could also
    // use [dict setObject:self.titleTextField.text forKey:@"title] , 
    // but that's outdated and less clear.
    dict[@"title"] = self.titleTextField.text;

    // Log out the value to confirm
    NSLog(@"title : %@", dict[@"title"]);
}
```

Based on the misunderstandings I see in your code, I'd recommend some reading:

- [Values and Collections: Dictionaries Collect Key-Value Pairs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH7-SW22)
- [Encapsulating Data: Properties Encapsulate an Object's Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW2)

Comment: Thanks @Riley ! That code makes perfect sense, and is actually more clearer and simple. When I run that function (i.e. press the button in the simulator) I am getting this fatal error. Which is strange, given I don't call setObjectForKey anywhere? 

**Any ideas?**

`2015-02-15 16:37:36.711 TodoApp[50163:607] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: title)'`

Comment: The error message is telling you what's wrong: the value (in this case, `self.titleTextField.text`) is `nil`. `NSDictionary` cannot store `nil` values. This means either that the text field's `text` property is `nil`, or, more likely, that `self.titleTextField` is itself `nil`. You should check with a breakpoint or an `NSLog`.

Comment: Yup, self.titleTextField doesn't return anything. I will make sure it's linked properly. @riley